# RecyclerView incorrect manual positioning

Tags: android

I'm trying to align some items inside a `RecyclerView` with others outside it. However, seems like all my tries are failing.

**What I'm trying to do specifically**: I have a couple of views as a header which are aligned using various methods* then a RecyclerView just below it, in its same parent, stretching the whole width, that inflates views.

**The problem**: Items inside the RecyclerView do not align perfectly to the items outside of it. **Knowing that** I'm using the same layout for both the parent and the items! And knowing that whatever method I used for horizontal alignment for the header items, is exactly used the same way for each item inflated for the RecyclerView. AND knowing that both items have same properties (they're TextViews, same size, width, height, etc...)

**What methods have I tried?** FOR BOTH SIDES (up and down), I tried the following:

1. Using ConstraintLayout for both parent and item layouts, and stretching the items between both start and end of parent, then using the constraint ratio to position it exactly where I want. Outcome for header is different from that of RecyclerView holders.
2. Using a TableLayout with children stretched across the whole width, same number of columns, same stretching, still different outcome, not pixel perfect.
3. Placing the header views exactly how I want, but not using any Android placement 'methodology' at all, but instead getX() and setX() later inside the adapter (using .post() so I ensure the position is accurate after inflation) and STILL the same wrong placement.

What am I missing? Shouldn't a RecyclerView inflating children that span the whole width when I specify they should match_parent? I tried debugging the X values for header and view holders, THEY'RE THE SAME but my eyes see different things. I delayed it for some milliseconds but this didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem turned out that whatever method I used, if the `TextView`s widths were `wrap_content` it'll always fit the word inside it. The solution was setting the width to 0dp and let the parent `ViewGroup` balance everything evenly. In my case I used a `TableLayout`.